# jQuery .hover appear 2 buttons

Tags: jquery

I have this problem for 3 days. yeah i know its so long and i am so stress about it.

the problem is when i do {.hover} i want 2 buttons appear.

the codes is

```
// HOVER
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#static").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "350");
        $(this).find('img#previewbut');
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "350");
        $(this).find('img#previewbut');  
    });
});
```

the form

```
<li>
    <p>' . $yValue['title'] . '</p>
    <span class="time timeright">' . $yValue['time'] . '</span>

    <a class="videoThumb4" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $yValue['videoid'] . '" id="static">
    ' . $yValue['description'] . '                      
    </a>
    <img src="img/preview.png" id="previewbut" />
</li>
```

what do i need to fix for the jquery?

Comment: `$(this).find('img#previewbut')` - this is effectively a no-op; you're not doing anything with what you find. Perhaps it should be written like this: `$(this).parent().find('img#previewbut').hide()`, no?

Answer (score 1):

did you mean ?

```
 $("#static").hover(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(350);
        $(this).closest("li").find('#previewbut').show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeIn(350);
        $(this).closest("li").find('#previewbut').hide();  
  });
```

Comment: +1 OP can use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` to animate the appearance

Comment: Yes, when it hover the hover is working properly, but when i click the button the buttons is block or it was href. heres the link of the page. http://cocopop12.site11.com/search/index.php

Comment: What i was trying to do last 3 days was to hover the list of the videos and view the buttons preview & select.